# Python comparison of 2 list and get custom output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, collections, comparison

I am working on a use case and stuck with implementation.

Consider a list `totalAnimalCharList = ['x','y','z','a','b','c']`

Consider a constant object AnimalType as below -:

```py
class AnimalType():
    type_1 = {
        'id': 1,
        'animalCharList': ['x','y','z','a'],
    }
    type_2 = {
        'id': 2,
        'animalCharList': ['z'],
    }
    type_3 = {
        'id': 3,
        'animalCharList': ['c'],
    }
```

Now based on the list `totalAnimalCharList` we need to find it's id. For example need to compare `totalAnimalCharList` and animalCharList( which is in `AnimalType` class) and since `totalAnimalCharList` has every element of type_1 i.e. `['x','y','z','a']`, we need to return `id=1` and reiterate to compare with other ids in the list and return all matched ids.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana Sorry, I am new to Python and don't have any idea even how to try this comparison of lists.

Comment: Well, where did get this problem from and what strategy do you have for solving this?

Comment: Convert the lists to sets, and use its `issubset()` method.

Comment: Don't use separate variables. Put all the `type_X` dictionaries in a list so you can loop over it.

Comment: I am working on a project task where I came over this use case and I am stuck. Strategy is this way-: iterate over AnimalType type_X and compare each animalCharList with totalAnimalCharList . If animalCharList is a subset of totalAnimalCharList then store it's id in a ID_list and continue iteration for next type_X and keep appending ids in the ID_list.

Comment: Ok, so you've got some algorithms there. You should try to write one of them and post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution to your original problem (but I also offer a simplified solution without `class` etc. - that is actually easier for beginner):

```py
totalAnimalCharList = ["x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c"]


class AnimalType:
    type_1 = {
        "id": 1,
        "animalCharList": ["x", "y", "z", "a"],
    }
    type_2 = {
        "id": 2,
        "animalCharList": ["z"],
    }
    type_3 = {
        "id": 3,
        "animalCharList": ["c"],
    }


def get_type(lst):
    for k, v in vars(AnimalType).items():
        if k.startswith("type_") and set(v["animalCharList"]).issubset(lst):
            yield v["id"]


print(list(get_type(totalAnimalCharList)))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

Other solution: Use just list with dictionaries and convert the lists there to sets:

```py
types = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "animalCharList": {"x", "y", "z", "a"},
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "animalCharList": {"z"},
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "animalCharList": {"c"},
    },
]


def get_type(lst):
    for t in types:
        if t["animalCharList"].issubset(lst):
            yield t["id"]


print(list(get_type(totalAnimalCharList)))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```